# Category Page navigation Issue in magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, navigation

I am using magento 1.9.2.3 my customer are facing problem when they are visiting the category page from frontend. Like one category have 10 pages if customer select the product from 5th page and click on the back button then it should be stay on 5th page but now it move to the 1st page of the category.

Can anyone let me know how can i fix this issue?

thanks

Comment: Long after you experiencing the same problem. Have you found the solution?